# How to emit object using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I have a code like, I have a problem with sending response.

```
socket.on('findUserMessages', (userName) => {
    io.sockets.connected[socket.id].emit('Checking-message', {
        type: 'ss',
        text: bot,
        user: 'bot'
    });

    var dupa = db.chat.find({ user: userName }, function(err, docs) {
        userName = userName
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('load old messages', docs)
    })

    io.emit('private message', dupa);
})
```

My node console output is like

```
[ { _id: 5888bdd6cef7952e38821f35,
text: 'O rajciu rajciu',
user: 'Adam',
time: 2017-01-25T15:01:42.733Z }]
```

I know that output is not a JSON string, how to solve that? I was trying to use .toArray() but without succes.

That might be silly question but I am stuck with it for a long time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Comment: You need to emit the result inside the callback.  `io.emit('private message', docs);`

Comment: I don't know where to start. what does `userName = userName` do?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ this 'docs' object is not a valid JSON object, thats the main problem.

Comment: @PiotrKaliński `docs` is an array of objects. As long as it doesn't include a function, you can send it through the socket. what you are trying to send is not `docs`. move the `emit` after `console.log`, and replace `dupa` with `docs`.

Comment: io.emit('private message', JSON.stringify(docs)); is not working, thanks a lot!

Comment: @PiotrKaliński you don't need to stringify it.

Answer (score -2):

Convert to json your result before emitting it. Try to emit `JSON.stringify(dupa)`.

**EDIT**
Your output is actually JSON already (JSON array), so if you want to get only JSON string on client side, convert your output to string there (`JSON.strigify(result)` on client side on receiving the emit event).

Comment: I was trying that, got null in browser console

Comment: That's not the issue @Arman P. He's actually emitting `null`. which is the return value of an async function.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Yeah, just noticed that he's not emitting from callback.